# Hide Adsense based on cookie

Tags: javascript, adsense

I'd like to not show Adsense for logged in members, using javascript and based on a cookie. Both types of members see the same html, as it's cached from the server. I know I could just hide the containing div, but I believe that is against the TOS and would also count as a false impression. The actual google script cannot be changed. I think I just need to somehow stop it loading the show_ads.js using some javascript before or after the google code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-555";
google_ad_slot = "555";
google_ad_width = 468;
google_ad_height = 15;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

Comment: @porum - Moving to StackExchange per [Pro Webmasters FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq). Please inquire at [Pro Webmasters Meta](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/) if you have any questions regarding the migration of this question.

Comment: Does it have to be javascript?  Manipulating cookies in JS is something of a pain.  What server side scripting are you using to generate your page?

Comment: Ignore the cookies. The important part is being able to optionally show the ads or not based on some criterion on the client. Server code is .Net MVC. I'm trying to load the script via a partial view using a jQuery Ajax Get, but the page hangs on loading the google script, although it works ok with a simple alert in a separate script.

Comment: From everything I've read, loading the google ads via ajax after the page load is not possible. In particular google can't read the page content to serve up relevant ads.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet would be to remove the adsense code using server-side scripting (PHP, ASP, etc).  Here's some pseudo code for PHP:

```
<?php
if (!$loggedin) {
?>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-555";
google_ad_slot = "555";
google_ad_width = 468;
google_ad_height = 15;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a client-side solution, so that the server can produce & cache the same html for everybody - anonymous members, logged-in members, paying-members. I'd prefer not not have 3 server-side-cached copies of everything. I can vary the client processing based on a cookie, but I don't think just putting something like "if (loggedin){...}" around the google code in javascript will stop it loading the google show_ads.js, and the google script is not allowed to be modified.

Possibly it needs google's Ajax Adsense product, but they have discontinued that.

Comment: At this point, I am using a server solution to handle non-cached pages, and am not showing ads on some cached pages that I would like to show them on.